# Trace various patterns strategically - python regex

Tags: python, nlp, screen-scraping, text-extraction

I have to extract information from PDF documents, all documents have the same structure. I use the following regular expressions:

```
regex_objetivos = r"Objetivo([\s\S]*)(?=3\s*\.\s*Justi)"
regex_claves = r"Palabras\s+clave([\s\S]*?)(?:Intro|Introduc|1\s*.)"
regex_resumen = r"Resumen([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*Palabras\s*clave)"
regex_directores =r"Directores:\s*([\s\S]*?)(?:\n|\r\n?)" here
```

The way I extract is as follows:

```
            if not b_resumen:
                match = re.search(regex_resumen, text)
                if match:
                    b_resumen = True
                    resumen = match.group(1).strip()
                else:
                    resumen = "no encontrado"

            if not b_claves:
                b_claves = True
                match = re.search(regex_claves, text)
                #print(text)
                if match:
                    claves = match.group(1).strip()
                else:
                    claves = "no encontrado"

            if not b_directores:
                match = re.search(regex_directores, text)
                if match:
                    b_directores = True
                    directores = match.group(1).split(',')
                else:
                    directores = ["no encontrado"]

            if not b_objetivos:
                match = re.search(regex_objetivos, text)
                if match:
                    b_objetivos = True
                    objetivos = match.group(1)
                    break
                else:
                    match = re.search(r"Objetivo([\s\S]*)(?=$)", text)
                    if match:
                        b_objetivos = True
                        objetivos = match.group(1)
                        break
                    else:
                        objetivos = "no encontrado"
```

My question is, if the documents always have the same structure, is there a way to optimize my match in such a way that the searches are sequential without searching from 0?

I try to optimize my code so that the automation time is less

Comment: For a compiled pattern the `search` method allows to specify a start position for searching. For a match the `match.end(1)` returns the position after the match of the first group. This position can be fed into the `search` call to continue searching from there.

Comment: thanks a lot @MichaelButscher, I should have checked the documentation first